# why disable-shared in gcc 4.7 build together with gmp mpfr mpc for native compile?

Tags: gmp, mpfr, mpc, gcc4.7

enviroment:
cpu: XEON NEHALEM E5530
os:  SUSE 10 SP2
gcc: 4.1.2

m4,binutils,autoconf,automake: UPDATED newest for required by gcc 4.7 build.
PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH set correct.

object: native optimization for gcc php httpd.

---

```
with -march=nocona -O2 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer  
gcc 4.1.2  gmp,mpfr,mpc OK  
gcc 4.1.2  gcc4.7 with gmp,mpfr,mpc OK  

with -march=native -O2 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer  
gcc 4.7  gmp,mpfr,mpc OK  
gcc 4.7  gcc4.7 with gmp,mpfr,mpc OK 

newest built gcc 4.7  
gcc 4.7  ppl,cloog OK  

gcc 4.7 build source tree together with gmp,mpfr,mpc,ppl,cloog  
error in configure ppl because not found gmp library.  

gcc 4.7 build source tree for native compile together with gmp,mpfr,mpc without ppl and cloog OK
```

But disable-shared added by system through checking config.log in subdirectories, though explicitly gcc 4.7 configure --enable-shared --disable-static.
Configure parameters in ppl are not listed in ppl's configure help.

Answer (score 0):

> But disable-shared added by system through checking config.log in subdirectories, though explicitly gcc 4.7 configure --enable-shared --disable-static

[gcc builds in several stages](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html). Early stages use `--disable-shared` switch regardless.